# asp.net mvc multiple areas, multiple authentication methods, same database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

Just look for a quick bit of advice on the best way to proceed.

Looking at building a new asp.net mvc app that will contain four different areas with three different authentication models.

Area 1 - public, no authentication, db read only public information
Area 2 - ASP.NET Identity, db write client information
Area 3 - Organizational accounts (Azure AD, domain a), db write all
Area 4 - Organizational accounts (Azure AD, domain b), db read only client information

All these areas will connect to the same database, preferably using different logins to restrict access.

Is this possible or should I bite the bullet and build 4 apps (ugh).

Cheers
Adam

Comment: Possible. But if you have an option to build different apps, I would do that - in a long term you will reduce your complexity, and not just because of Authentication

Comment: Appreciate the assistance :) Will go down the path of multiple apps. Thanks!!